# Odoo 11 Switch between tree views for the same model based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I have Created a model in odoo 11, I want to load different tree views based on a filter, these tree views will be showing different columns and column headers

Comment: Using Js is possible, You can render any type of table with respect to the change of filter.

Comment: Will i be able to call a function in python in the java script? if so please respond with a sample code that works in odoo 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or I could create groups and actions and the different views to load for each user in a specific group using domains in the action.
I think that could also actually work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show tree view according to user you can do that by applying group on views or if you want to show different view according to different value you can set thier view id.

Comment: Thanks Akshay but this is not what I am looking for, this i can achieve but will not help me overcome the challenge

Comment: My Intent is not to vary the tree based on user groups and privileges but rather, vary the tree view based on a condition that can be implemented on filters

Comment: You can't do that from there you can create multiple actions and call them according to your filter  because  at action time its views is loaded.